# Is there a command to alter active window opacity?

Tags: kubuntu

In Kubuntu 16.04, I can set the opacity for an application's active window using the system's GUI:

[image: Active Opacity]

But is there a way to do so using a command that can accessed via a script (and a keyboard shortcut)?

Answer (score 1):

### Using the keyboard

It's possible to use the keyboard to decrease or increase the opacity of the active window by increments of 5%.

To do so, open `System Settings` > `Global Shortcuts` > `KWin`. In the `Action` column, find `Decrease Opacity of Active Window by 5%` and `Increase Opacity of Active Window by 5%`. Set appropriate keyboard shortcuts for each of the actions and click `Apply`. That's it.

[image: Decrease/Increase Active Window Opacity]

### Using the mouse wheel

If one prefers, there's a option using the mouse wheel.
Open `System Settings` > `Window Management` > `Window Behavior` and click on the `Window Actions` tab.

In the section titled `Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame`, click on the dropdown next to `Mouse wheel` and choose `Change Opacity`. Then click `Apply`.
Note: you have a choice of <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Meta</kbd> (aka <kbd>Super</kbd>) as the modifier key.

[image: Using the mouse wheel]